# Reducing mod $n$ in $\mathcal O_{\mathbb Q (\zeta_n)}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I noticed (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1247599/are-the-eisenstein-integers-the-ring-of-integers-of-some-algebraic-number-field)) that $\mathbb Z[\zeta_n]\cong \mathbb Z[\omega]$ and $\mathbb Z[i]$ when $n=3,4$ respectively and $\zeta_n$ is the primitive $n$th root of unity. Here $\mathbb Z[\omega]$ is the Eisenstein integers and $\mathbb Z[i]$ is the Gaussian integers.

When working with the Eisenstein integers, to prove whether or not an integer remains prime in $Z[\omega] \cong \mathcal O_{\mathbb Q(\zeta_3)}$, we reduce modulo $3$. The first time I saw this, I found it to be an extremely unintuitive step. Similarly in the Gaussian integers, to prove whether or not an integer remains prime in $Z[i] \cong \mathcal O_{\mathbb Q(\zeta_4)}$, we reduce modulo $4$.

Is there some deep reason why there is a distinctive "threeness" about $\mathbb Z[\omega]$ and "fourness" about $\mathbb Z[i]$? Does this generalise to $\mathcal O_{\mathbb Q (\zeta_n)}$ having a "$n$-ness" to it? Will reducing modulo $n$ suddenly become a good idea in $\mathcal O_{\mathbb Q (\zeta_n)}$? If so, why does this happen?

(I may be just getting ahead of myself, as I haven't had a chance to properly look through the references given to me in the above link. If this is some deep result whose proof I won't understand, it's fine just to tell me to read a book and find out.)

Comment: The rings for $n = 3$ and $n = 4$ are *quadratic*, so the only choice a prime has is to stay prime or split (or ramify, but that happens once, for $p = 2$ in $\mathbf Z[i]$ and $p = 3$ in $\mathbf Z[\omega]$). For the ring of integers $\mathbf Z[\zeta_n]$ of a general cyclotomic field, the splitting behavior of a prime number $p$ that doesn't divide $n$ is determined by the subgroup $\langle p \bmod n\rangle$ of  $(\mathbf Z/(n))^\times$. In particular, $p$ is prime in $\mathbf Z[\zeta_n]$ iff $p \bmod n$ generates $(\mathbf Z/(n))^\times$. Often there's no such $p$, e.g., $n = 8$ or $15$.

Comment: In $\mathbf Z[\zeta_8]$, for instance, if $p \equiv 1 \bmod 8$ then the ideal  $(p)$ splits into a product of four prime ideals and for all other odd prime numbers $p$ the ideal $(p)$ is a product of two prime ideals (each with norm $p^2$). No prime number stays prime in $\mathbf Z[\zeta_8]$.

Comment: You're right in to guess that there's something about $p \bmod n$ (what you call $n$-ness) that tells you how the ideal $(p)$ factors in $\mathbf Z[\zeta_n]$. It's because $\mathbf Q(\zeta_n)/\mathbf Q$ is a Galois extension with Galois group isomorphic to $(\mathbf Z/(n))^\times$, and for a Galois extension $K/\mathbf Q$ there is a close relation between how an unramified prime $p$ factors in $K$ and a certain conjugacy class in ${\rm Gal}(K/\mathbf Q)$ related to $p$, called its Frobenius conjugacy class. If the Galois group is abelian, the conjugacy class becomes an element.

Comment: More simply, in a quadratic field $K = \mathbf Q(\sqrt{d})$ like your two examples, the way an unramified *odd* prime $p$ decomposes in $\mathcal O_K$ is related to how $x^2 - d \bmod p$ decomposes, which is related to the Legendre symbol $(\frac{d}{p})$. The quadratic reciprocity law implies that $(\frac{d}{p})$ for fixed $d$ is determined by $p \bmod 4d$; when $d \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ the Legendre symbol $(\frac{d}{p})$ is even determined by $p \bmod d$. Taking $d = -1$ and $d = -3$ recovers your observation about the role of $p \bmod 4$ (same as mod $-4$) and $p \bmod 3$ (same as mod $-3$).

Comment: @KCd Thanks so much for the comments!! This is really interesting. I'll have to look into this more after my exams! I may even see if I can do a fourth year project related to this next year. (If you were to turn this into an answer, I would happily accept it)

Comment: A fourth-year project?  Just read a book on algebraic number theory (e.g, Samuel's "Algebraic Number Theory" and learn more about it. There's no need to make it a formal "project."