# Eisenstein integers; finding a condition to be a unit using a multiplicative function.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, eisenstein-integers

**Context $1$:** Let $E = \Bbb Z [w] = \{m + nw \in \Bbb C \hspace{.1cm}| \hspace{.1cm} m,n \in \Bbb Z\}$ the domain of the Eisenstein integers. Doing some work, we know that $\omega^2 = \bar{\omega} $. Also, $\omega^3 = 1 \Leftrightarrow \omega \bar{\omega} = 1$. Furthermore, $\omega^2 + \omega = -1$.

**Showing that $E$ is a domain.** Since $E \subset \Bbb C$ and $\Bbb C$ is ring, then $E$ is a subring of $\Bbb C$. This also implies that $E$ is a subdomain of $\Bbb C$ and thus it is also a domain.

**Context $2$:** Define the function $\eta: E \rightarrow \Bbb N_0$ such that $z \rightarrow |z|^2$. From this we can easily see that this function is multiplicative since the norm is, and it satisfies $\eta(z) = 0 \Leftrightarrow z = 0$. Furthermore, $\eta(m+n\omega) = m^2 + n^2 - mn$. This is an euclidian evalutation and so $E$ is an euclidian domain. Note that $\eta(m+n\omega) = \frac{1}{4}((2m-n)^2+3n^2)$.

**Question.** Show that $m+n\omega$ is a unit **iff** $\eta(m+nw) = 1$.

**My attempt.** Suppose that $u = m + n\omega$ is a unit in $E$. Then, we have that
\begin{equation*}
1 = \eta(1) = \eta(u u^{-1}) = \eta(u) \eta(u^{-1})
\end{equation*}
Obviously, both $\eta(u)$ and $\eta(u^{-1})$ must be in $\Bbb N_0$ and so the only option we have is that $\eta(u) = 1 = \eta(u^{-1})$. This proves that $\eta(u) = \eta(m+n\omega) = 1$.

Now, we need to prove that $\eta(u) = \eta(m+nw) = 1 \Rightarrow u$ is an unit in $E$. I don't know how to proceed to prove this implication.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: I would multiply $m+n\omega$ by $(m-n)-n\omega$ and call it a day. (Note that $1+\omega+\omega^2=(1-\omega^3)/(1-\omega)$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\eta(a+b\omega)=(a+b\omega)(a+b\bar\omega)$ where $a,b$ are integers. So if $\eta(a+b\omega)=1$ then $(a+b\omega)(a+b\bar\omega)=1$ and $a+b\omega$ is a unit.

Comment: Does this prove that $a + b \omega$ is a unit in $E$ ? If so, why? I understand what you did, but this is valid for $N_0$ only or also proves that $a + b\omega$ is a unit in $E$?

Comment: Yes, in $E$ because $\bar \omega=-1-\omega\in E$.

Comment: Oh, and since $1$ is the neutral element in $E$ we have just found that $a+b \overline{\omega}$ is the inverse of $(a+b \omega)$ in $E$, right? (Thus proving $(a+b\omega)$ is an unit)

Comment: Yes, if $a+b\omega$ has norm $1$.

Comment: Got it! Can you tell me if you agree with what I did to show that $E$ is a domain?

Comment: It is fine. ${}$

Answer (score 0):

We already know that an element $u$ in the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ of a number field $K$ is a unit if and only if its norm equals $\pm 1$, see for example this duplicate:

[Units in ring of integers are exactly those with norm {-1,1}](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2002104/units-in-ring-of-integers-are-exactly-those-with-norm-1-1)

For $K=\Bbb Q(\omega)$, the norm of an element $a+b\omega$ in $\mathcal{O}_K=\Bbb Z[\omega]$ cannot be negative, because of
$$N(a+b\omega)=a^2-ab+b^2 = \left( a - \frac{1}{2}b\right)^2 + \frac{3}{4}b^2,$$
as you have stated in your context 2 text (with $\eta(n+m\omega)$). So we are done.

Comment: Two things: 1) If it is a duplicate, why did you post an answer instead of voting to close. 2) Why do you think that $\Bbb Z[\omega]={\mathcal O}_K$?

Comment: @markvs 2) because of another duplicate at this site [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1247599/are-the-eisenstein-integers-the-ring-of-integers-of-some-algebraic-number-field). And 1), because it seems not an exact duplicate, but rather uses it. It is not immediately clear that $-1$ cannot arise.

Comment: This histeria with various duplicates (exact, not exact, abstract, concrete, dupe of a FAQ, FAQ of a dupe) is really annoying.

Comment: @markvs Yes, I agree. But many people spend a lot of time for giving good answers here, and their posts should not be ignored. Also it seems that you find it good not to close this as a duplicate since you gave a nice short answer. Still, that we have $N(u)=\pm 1$ much more generally should be mentioned, I think (or remembered at least).